# Proof verification: $|X|=|Y|=m \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists exactly $m!$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

**Lemma.** For sets $X, Y$ with $|X|=|Y|=m \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists exactly $m! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot m$ pairwise distinct bijective maps between $X$ and $Y$.

*Proof is left as an exercise.*

---

**Attempt:** Prove Lemma.

*(1)* Show true for $m=1$. $X=\{1\}$, $Y=\{a\}$. Number of possible arrangements $1!$, arrangements: (1,a).

*(2)* Assume true for $m=k$. $X = \{1,2 \ldots , k_X \}$, $Y=\{a, b \ldots k_Y \}$. Number of possible arrangements $k!$. Note that $k! \implies m!$

*(3)* Show true for $m=k+1$. $X = \{1,2, \ldots, k_X, k_X+1\}$, $Y = \{a,b, \ldots, k_Y, k_Y+1\}$. Number of possible arrangements $(k+1)!$

$(k+1)! = m!$

$m! = k!$ *(from step (2))*

*(4)* $\therefore$ by the process of mathematical induction, for $m$ elements there exists $m!$ pairwise distinct bijective maps between $X$ and $Y$.

---

> I'd like to know if I have been redundant in some step or wrote some nonsense along the way.

---

Liesen, J., Mehrmann, V. 2015. Linear Algebra. Berlin, Germany.: Springer.

Comment: for the induction step (3), I would say that the first element of $X$ maps to any of the $k+1$ elements of $Y$, and by the induction hypothesis there are $k!$ possible arrangements for the remaining $k$ elements of $X$ to be mapped to the remaining $k$ elements of $Y$, so by the [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) there are $(k+1)k!=(k+1)!$ possible bijective maps from $X$ to $Y$; it doesn't really make sense to say $(k+1)!=m!$ and $m!=k!$ as you did; also did you mean $x_{k+1}$ where you typed $k_X+1$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Typo in $k_{x+1}$ and $k_{y+1}$. Should've been $x_{k+1}$ and $y_{k+1}$ as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In step (2), I would denote the sets as $X=\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k\}$ and $Y=\{y_1,y_2,\dots,y_k\}$.

For the induction step (3), it doesn't really make sense to say $(k+1)!=m!$ and $m!=k!$ as you did.  I would say that the first element of $X=\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{k+1}\}$ is mapped to any of the $k+1$ elements of $Y$, and by the induction hypothesis there are $k!$ possible arrangements for the remaining $k$ elements of $X$ to be mapped to the remaining $k$ elements of $Y$, so by the [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) there are $(k+1)k!=(k+1)!$ possible bijective maps from $X$ to $Y$.

Comment: If $(k+1)!$ are the possible bijective maps, how can you conclude there are $m!$ possible bijective maps (as the lemma originally states) without saying $(k+1)!=m!$ ?

Comment: If you want to put it that way, you could say that in step (2), we assume that when $m=k$ then there are $m!=k!$ arrangements, and in step (3), we have shown that, under the assumption of step (2), when $m=k+1$ there are $m!=(k+1)!$ arrangements; but it doesn't make much sense to say $m!=k!$ at the end of step $3$